# Convert a PHP $_FILES array to another array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a form submitted with a single input of type of file name: `photo[profile][]`. I get the this array:

```
Array
(
[photo] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [profile] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
                        [1] => Desert.jpg
                    )

            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [profile] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image/jpeg
                        [1] => image/jpeg
                    )

            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [profile] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9DCC.tmp
                        [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9E0B.tmp
                    )

            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [profile] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                    )

            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [profile] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 879394
                        [1] => 845941
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

So, i want a recursive function which will convert my array to this:

```
Array
(
    [photo] => Array
        (
            [profile] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
                        [type] => image/jpeg
                        [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9DCC.tmp
                        [error] => 0
                        [size] => 845941
                    )
                   [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Desert.jpg
                        [type] => image/jpeg
                        [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9DCC.tmp
                        [error] => 0
                        [size] => 845941
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I need this because i want to upload more photos and set a config for each group of files.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: This is not rocket science. At least try to do it for yourself. Then if you fail you can ask here for help

Comment: I really tried to make this. I can't figure what so bad in this example. I know that could make a few loops and solve my problem, by this is not really smart and useful...

Comment: Nothing wrong with the example. The issue is you are asking US to write all your code for you. **SO != Free coders**

Answer (score 1):

There is no native one, just use a loop.

```
$result = array();

foreach($_FILES as $key => $value){
   foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
       foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3){
           foreach($value3 as $index => $value4){
               $result[$key][$key3][$index][$key2] = $value4;
           }
       }         
   }         
}
```

Comment: This is good, but what if my array us deeper? Here is come the problem. That's why i need a recursive function. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_column` function(available since PHP 5.5) and `array_column` function:

```
if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) {
    $quantity = count($_FILES['photo']['size']['profile']);        
    $photos = array_column($_FILES['photo'], 'profile');
    $ordered_list = ['photo' => ['profile' => []]];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $quantity; $i++) {
        $ordered_list['photo']['profile'][] = array_combine(['name', 'type', 'tmp_error', 'error', 'size'], array_column($photos, $i));
    }        
}
```

Now the `$ordered_list` contains the needed grouped data